# Bootstrap's Tab Control fires code for all tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Bootstrap 3.0 Tab Strip on my Angular 1.5.8 MVC asp.net web application.

Currently I have 5 tabs.  Each tab makes an expensive data call to the server to retrieve data.

Currently, when the page loads, all the code for ALL 5 tabs gets executed because I have all the code in one controller file.

Is there a way to ONLY load the data for the default tab?  As such, the data call for the other tabs will only fire when each tab is clicked?

Also, is there a way to attach an angular click event to each tab?

Can you please send me an example.

Thanks

BTD

Comment: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would be to declare these calls in functions so they won't be called on page load and then only call the initial tab function in the controller.  Something like the following in your controller:

```
$scope.Tab1 = function() {...};
$scope.Tab2 = function() {...};
$scope.Tab3 = function() {...};
$scope.Tab1();
```

And then on the tabs themselves you will just use the `ng-click` method to trigger the loading of the other data:

```
<a href="#tab2" ng-click="Tab2()">Tab 2</a>
```

Comment: Eric G
You're a genius.  Many many thanks!  Have a great day.  That worked.  Tom

Comment: @user3540895 thanks!  Want to mark it correct if it worked for you?  :) Thanks!

Comment: Sure, how do I do that?

Comment: There should be a green check next to my answer that you can click.  This may help you too http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I don't see the green check box next to your answer.  As I guess I don't have enough reputations.  How else can I give you credit for this?

Comment: @user3540895 Oh, I guess it is a gray check mark.  You click it to make it green.  It should be to the left of my answer underneath the up/down vote section.  And I think anyone can mark answers on their own questions regardless of rep but maybe not.  If not, no worries!